# TypeError: unsupported format string passed to NoneType.__format__(I do not know what this means)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, error-handling

This is my code I do not know what this error means.Anyone please tell me where I am doing wrong, and what should be correct code.Help is very much appreciated.

Code:

```
cart = ['S/n'," "*10, 'Items', " " * 15, "Quantity", " " * 8, "Unit Price", " " * 6, "Price"]
total_pricee = 0
pricee = 0
count=1
cart_number=[count]
def invalid_input(Quantity):
    while Quantity >= '5' or Quantity < '0':
        Quantitiy = input("Please key in a valid quantity(Between 1 to 4):")
        if Quantity <= '5' and Quantity > '0':
            return Quantity
            break
        break
    while not Quantity.isdigit():
        Quantity = input('Invalid input.Please enter a valid input:')
        while Quantity.isdecimal() == False:
            break

def add_to_cart(name, Quantity, price):
    global total_pricee, pricee,count
    cart.append('\n')
    cart.append('{:<10s}'.format(str(count)+'.'))
    cart.append('{:^10s}'.format(name))
    cart.append('{:^30s}'.format(Quantity))
    cart.append('{:^10s}'.format('$' + '{:.2f}'.format(float(price))))
    pricee = '{:.2f}'.format(float(Quantity) * price)
    cart.append('{:^23s}'.format('$' + str(pricee)))
    total_pricee += float(pricee)
    count = count +1
while True:
    print('[1] Water')
    print('[2] rice')
    print('[3] ice')
    print('[0] View Cart')
    opt = input("Select option:")
    if opt > '3' or opt < '0':
        print("Select valid option!")
    if opt == '3':
        qunt = input("How many would you like?")
        qunt=invalid_input(qunt)
        nam3 = "Ice"
        add_to_cart(nam3, qunt, 2)
    if opt == '1':
        qunt2 = input("How many would you like?")
        quan2=invalid_input(qunt2)
        nam2 = "Water"
        add_to_cart(nam2, qunt2, 3)
    if opt == '2':
        qunt1 = input("How many would you like?")
        qunt1=invalid_input(qunt1)
        nam1 = "Rice"
        add_to_cart(nam1, qunt1, 5)
    if opt == "0":
        print(*cart)
        print("Total price until now:", "$" + '{:.2f}'.format(total_pricee))
        print('Would you like to check out?')
        print('[1] Yes')
        print('[2] No')
        checkout=input("Please select an option:")
        if checkout=='1':
            print('You have bought',count,'items')
            print("Please pay""$" + '{:.2f}'.format(total_pricee))
            print('Thank you for shopping with us!')
            exit()
```

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to NoneType.__format__
```

I just stated learning python and I do not know what this error means. Anyone please tell me where I am doing wrong, and what should be correct code. Help is very much appreciated.Thank you so much!

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: Welcome to SOF ! The error should be indicating a `line-number` , please add those details too

Comment: 2 errors.
1st: line 53, in <module>
    add_to_cart(nam1, qunt1, 5)
2nd:line 25, in add_to_cart
    cart.append('{:^30s}'.format(Quantity))
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to NoneType.__format__

Answer (score 1):

Look at the lines of code where you're using the ***.format*** method. In at least one of them, you have a null value and you're trying to use the ***.format*** method on it- which you cannot do. 
Hence the error: **NoneType.format**

Print all your variable before each operation or add some logic to check on null values, such as

```
if name != None:
    cart.append('{:^10s}'.format(name))
```

Comment: He means that one of the calls to like `'...'.format(variable)` is wrong. It's wrong because the variable passed is null or not defined. His suggestion is to print the value formatted before the format line to debug which value is not defined and to add a condition to guard against calling format with an undefined value.